Function LaplaceGaussian Filter -> What exactly is standardized, if this option is chosen?
I try to figure out what the option Standardized->True for function LaplacianGaussianFilter exactly means. I understand that it guarantees that the sum over the Kernel is exactly zero. But what determines the range (min/max) of the kernel?
I find systematic differences in range when comparing the corresponding result obtained with matlab when convolving with a kernel constructed with fspecial('log', ...)
Is the Mathematica code available or the procedure optiona completely documented? I did also not find a reference for the option "Bessel", which is set as default.

I think everything is explained if you read the whole documentation for LaplacianGaussianFilter, together with Properties & Relations, and also GaussianMatrix, where you will find about "Bessel" vs "Gaussian" distinction. If you really have to, you can use GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[LaplacianGaussianFilter] to look at the source code.

@Domen: Thanks for the clarification! I wasn't aware that the documentation is “nested”, i.e. that more detailed explanations of a procedure are contained in the methods that are called during the calculation, e.g. that the Standardization and Bessel options are actually explained in GaussianMatrix.
Thanks also for the hint on how to print the definitions.
